# C++ fseek doesn't set to same position

Tags: c++, fseek

I need to return to a previous position in a file that I'm reading after a certain event. The file is opened in text read mode. So I get the read position of the file before reading the needed segment and after that I'm calling ftell to return me to that position. The problem is that it doesn't go to the position that I specified, it instead jumps ahead by two places.

To get the current position I'm using this simplified function.
I'm not sure if the fflush is necessary but it seems to make no difference in the result.

```
long GetCurPos(void)
{
    return ftell(file);
}
```

To open the file I'm simply using

```
void Open(void)
{
    file = fopen(path, "r");
}
```

To return to a previous position I'm using this simplified function.
It return a zero value.

```
void SetPos(long pos) const
{
    if (fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET)) LOG("ferror %d occured!", ferror(file));
}
```

And finally for function that causes the problems

```
bool TryPeekWord(char * value, size_t maxLen) const
{
    bool result = false;
    long start = GetCurPos();
    int c;
    size_t len; 

    for (len = 0; len < maxLen; len++)
    {
        c = fgetc(file);
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            *(value + len) = '\0';
            result = len > 0;
            break;
        }
        if ((c == ' ' || c == '\n') && len > 0)
        {
            *(value + len) = '\0';
            result = true;
            break;
        }
        *(value + len) = static_cast<char>(c);
    }

    SetPos(start);
    return result;
}
```

If I call fseek again after the SetPos call it will be the same value as start but if I then read from the file it will not return the expected characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you wrap that all up as a [mcve] please?

Comment: I'll do my best, I don't come her often sorry.

Comment: Thanks!  When you have create the example, *make sure it still has the problem*.  As far as I can see, your code is fine (apart from casting the result from `fgetc` to `char` *before* comparing against EOF - that can cause grief, but I don't think it is your problem.

Comment: Also, please include the test input in the example.

Comment: Use std::fstream, not the old FILE API.

Comment: `fflush(file);`for a read only file?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* -- I'm always suspicious of attempts to treat a file opened in text mode as if it was opened in binary mode.

Comment: are the 2 bytes it skips are \r\n?

Comment: The file I'm testing on causes this problem at position 101 in the file. When making a simplified version of the code and simply pasting in the line that causes this problem the problems disappears. The line was "v -0.723607 -0.447220 -0.525725\r\n" and it would return to the first '.' character. This is the 5th line in the file.

Comment: @Arzana -- The issue of opening a file in text mode and then attempting to do exact byte positioning on that file is many times rendered useless due to the underlying newline translation that goes on.

Comment: @Arzana You still haven't put together a [mcve].  Describing what your real code is doing using what you posted is not such an example.  We should be able to take the code you posted, and without having to edit anything, compile and run the code.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have been working on getting a proper example but I'm not having the problem in the example so it's a bit frustrating.

Comment: I have fixed the issue regarding the EOF check at least.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie He isn't actually attempting to treat a file opened in text mode as if it were opened in binary.  He is just seeking (with SEEK_SET) to a previous value returned by `ftell` - that is supposed to be an entirely legitimate operation, blessed by the standard.

Comment: @manni66 : *Why* should he use `std::fstream`?  As we don't understand his problem, there is a) no reason to suppose `std::fstream` will fix it; b) significant risk that `std::fstream` will hide it.

Comment: I have been trying to get a better example and during the course of this I found out that the file is somehow corrupt. I have moved the entire contents of the file to a new one and with the same code it works just fine.

Comment: Thank for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the course of improving my question to a proper standard I found that the file I was working on got corrupt. Maybe from moving to different operating system or something?
I copied over the contents of the old file into a new file and it worked fine again.